# Hadoop returns permission denied

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop (2.7) in cluster (two machines **hmaster** and **hslave1**). I installed hadoop in the folder /opt/hadoop/
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.rexamine.com/2015/02/installing-hadoop-2-6-0-on-centos-7/) but Iwhen I run the command start-dfs.sh, I got the following error about:

```
hmaster: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-hmaster.out
hmaster: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hmaster.out
hslave1: mkdir: impossible to create the folder « /opt/hadoop\r »: Permission denied
hslave1: chown: impossible to reach « /opt/hadoop\r/logs »: no file or folder of this type
```

/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-localhost.localdomain.out

I used the command chmod 777 for the folder hadoop in hslave but I still have this error.

Comment: What about the permissions on the parent dirs? i.e /opt? or /opt/hadoop?

Comment: I executed the following command on the slave node: chmod 777 /opt and chmod 777 /opt/hadoop/ . But I still have the same issue

Comment: Could you try creating this dir /opt/hadoop\r manually with the user your trying to start the service with and also why is there a backslash before r should be a forward slash. Check the *.XML conf files also

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using /opt/ use /usr/local/ if you get that permission issue again give the root permissions using **chmod**. I already configured hadoop 2.7 in 5 machines. Or else use "**Sudo chown user:user /*your log files directory*".**

Comment: I gave permissions to my master to read/write in /opt/ and /opt/hadoop/. However, my master creates a new folder hadoop and returns an error saying that it cannot find bin/ directory.

Comment: Ok. Say one thing how you are creating the Hadoop log which was in hdfs-site.xml. And I will send my documentation follow that one its worked for me. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Af2O6ErDLvWWxRTU83bFFWY3R6RmtjV1djT2Y1VlAwQV80

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have already gave master password less access to login slave.
Make sure you are logged in with username available on both servers.
(hadoop in your case, as tutorial you are following uses 'hadoop' user.)

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the '/etc/sudoer' file using 'sudo' or directly type 'visudo' in the terminal and add the following permission for newly created user 'hadoop' :-

> hadoop ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL

might it will resolved your issues.